# Как я могу передать функцию agree из callback_queries.py на main.py?

Tags: python, aiogram

Всем привет кто знает как можно передать функцию agree в main.py вот код

```
#callback_queries.py
from aiogram import types

async def agree(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, bot):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, "Спасибо за обращение!")

# main.py
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor 
from message_handlers import start
from config import TOKEN
from callback_queries import agree

bot = Bot(TOKEN)   
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

dp.register_message_handler(lambda msg: start(msg, bot), commands=['start'])
dp.register_callback_query_handler(
    lambda agre: start(agre ,bot=bot),
    lambda c: c.data == 'agree'
)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)

#inlineuttons.py
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup

agreemend = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton('✅ Yes I agree',callback_data='agree'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы её вызвать, пишешь `import и имя`

В начале кода лучше делай функцией `def имя`

Чтобы вызвать в нужный момент пишешь `имя():`